# Can I add extra callback to this.props.children on React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say this.props.children[0] is TouchableOpacity which is from parent.

And I want add extra callback to it in HERE. Is what I want possible? I can't find any solution for this.

Thanks.

```
export default class NewClassXXX extends React.Component{

    render()
    {
        newchildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
           //child is TouchableOpacity class in my code ***
           //I want to add LongPress callback by coding HERE. (like below)
           child.onLongPress = () => console.log('SUCESSS!!!'); //this code does not work.
           return child;
        }
        return {newchildren}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `React.cloneElement` method to achieve this like this

```
export default class NewClassXXX extends React.Component{

    render()
    {
        newchildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
           return React.cloneElement(child, {onLongPress: () => console.log('SUCESSS!!!')})
        }
        return {newchildren}
    }
```

Comment: OMG. Thanks brother. It works like a charm. I will flag this as a answer after 5 minutes delay.